# Performance issues wordpress

Tags: optimization, performance-testing, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

We tried to test the performance of two images on site’e homepage. We tested one image then the other one. Now the issue is the image which is having large size, better quality as well as large dimensions is giving us better speed results as compared to the image having small size and less quality even though it should have been opposite to it but help me figure out why is that. The image is the first image on site’s homepage.

Speed results: https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fhijrahpress.com%2F

Image that gives better results is named with large(having large size, dimensions and high quality) and other as small.

Large image:https://ibb.co/S6cK7sj

Small image:https://ibb.co/cFFhvdk

Large image currently used on homepage.

Comment: [Cross-posted from WordPress.SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/409153/209115) [and Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/140280/wordpress-performance-issue).

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion are to convert the png image to webp.
It should be sized to fit your page.  The image size on your webpage is 600 x 900.

I converted for you.  This is much improved.

[arabicgrammar.webp 600 x 900px](http://www.patrick-young.com/arabicgrammar.webp)